# customizing p-dynamicdialog templates in custom defined component in primeNG

Tags: angular, dialog, primeng

I'm using dynamic-dialog service to show a component as a modal and i couldn't find a way to replace the header , content and footer template with a custom defined template within my dialog component. is there a way to do that?

when opening a component with dialog service you can pass the header and the footer template as a string. but i have dependent methods in my component that doesn't fit in that solution.

```
<button
pButton
pRipple
type="button"
*ngIf="!item.isDisabledItem"
icon="fas fa-check"
class="p-button-rounded p-button-success"
(click)="openModal(formData[i]?.id)">
</button>
```

```
 openModal(id) {
    this.dialogRef.open(ViewAndCreateStationTicketTypeComponent, {
      data: {
        programId: this.programId,
        ticketTypeId: id,
      },
      style: { 'min-width': '50%', 'min-height': '50vh', overflow: 'auto' },
      modal: true,
      rtl: true,
    });
  }
```

i thought it might be similar to Ng-Bootsrap , when you pass the classes into view , the modal template should have the classes modal-header , modal-body and modal-footer.
but there is no and when i try that with primeNG dynamic dialog classes , it just become added to existing classes

if you have ideas , please share.
Thanks